# Mysql не всегда успевает обработать запросы

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

У меня возникла проблема при выполнении запросов в mysql.
Суть:
Скрипт написан на Node.JS библиотеки использую socket.io + mysql2

При многочисленном евенте (к примеру разом 100-500) на SIO должны сработать последовательные запросы в бд Пример кода:

```
const mPool = Mysql.createPool({
   host:               "",
   user:               "",
   password:           "",
   database:           "",
   port:               "",
   queueLimit:         0,
   connectionLimit:    150,
   waitForConnections: true
});

let dbP = mPool.promise();
Sio.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)
{
 socket.on('myEvent', async (data) =>
 {
    let MyData = JSON.parse(data);
    let [result1] = await dbP.query('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ?', 
    [MyData.id]).catch((error)=>{console.log(`query SELECT table error:  ${error}`)});
    if(!result1.length)
    {
        console.log(`Not found id: ${MyData.id}`);
    }
    else
    {
        let [result2] = await dbP.query('SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `id2` = ?', [MyData.id2]).catch((error)=>{console.log(`query SELECT table2 error: ${error}`)});
        if(!result2.length)
        {
            /*Тут выполняется мелкий код в виде цикла*/
            await dbP.query('INSERT INTO `table2` (`id2`, `param1`, `param2`, `param3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 0)', [MyData.id2, param1, param2])
            .then(() =>
            {
                Sio.to(socket.id).emit("MyResultEmmit", MyData);

            }).catch((error) => {console.log(`query INSERT table2 error: ${error}`)});//Часто получаю тут ошибку Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' Хотя запись с этим айди уже существует ощущение такое как буд-то запрос не успел обработаться перед верхним
        }
        else
        {
            /*Тут снова выполняется мелкий код в виде цикла*/
            await dbP.query('UPDATE `table2` SET `param1` = ?, `param2` = ? WHERE `id2` = ?', [param1, param2, MyData.id2])
            .then(() =>
            {
                Sio.to(socket.id).emit("MyResultEmmit", Event);
                QueueConnect = false;
            }).catch((error)=>{console.log(`query UPDATE table2: ${error}`)});
        }
    }
 });
});
```

Как исправить что бы БД успевала обработать?

---

Comment: Два селекта + 2 инсерта, и сервер не успевает обработать? у вас там что, пентиум сотый? Ну и - что именно означает "не успевает обработать"?

Comment: Вот именно что не пентиум нормальный зеон 12 поточный, я же говорю если 1 запрос отправить то все работает нормально а если к примеру 500-1000 запросов разом сделать из них обрабатывается 3-5  в мускуле, лимиты на сервере мускула я поднял поставил коннекты с 151 до 1000 не помогло

Comment: @隼SAPSAN А что происходит с остальными? они доходят? не успевают обработаться и закрываются? или что?

Comment: @Ceri, Они как будто пытаются одновременно выполнится

Comment: Каждый из 4 запросов общается с одной-единственной записью одной таблицы. В упор не вижу причин для тормозов, даже если таблицы пухлые и индексов нет. Чему равны MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR и MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS для используемой учётной записи? *поставил коннекты с 151 до 1000* Гм... а зачем?

Comment: @Akina,MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR и MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS там по 0 стоит без ограничений.
`Гм... а зачем?` Думал не хватает одновременных подключений для юзера

Comment: Рассмотрите возможность собрать select table2 / insert / update в одну операцию `insert into table2 ... on duplicate key update ...`  во первых это гораздо быстрее. Во вторых ваш текущий код подвержен состоянию гонки, если два запроса пользователей практически одновременно захотят обновить запись с одним и тем же id2 то возможна ситуация, что оба сделают select, ничего не найдут и уйдут в блок insert, при котором один из запросов свалится по ошибке, потому что второй успеет вставить запись. insert on duplicate автоматически лечит это

Comment: Если id автоинкрементный, ```insert into table2 ... on duplicate key update ...``` приводит к его увеличению в любом случае. Это не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел, помог mutex

```
const mPool = Mysql.createPool({
      host:               "",
      user:               "",
      password:           "",
      database:           "",
      port:               "",
      queueLimit:         0,
      connectionLimit:    150,
      waitForConnections: true
});

var Mutex = new Mutex();

let dbP = mPool.promise();
Sio.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    socket.on('myEvent', async (data) =>
    {
        const unlock = await Wait.lock();
        let MyData = JSON.parse(data);
        let [result1] = await dbP.query('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ?', 
        [MyData.id]).catch((error)=>{console.log(`query SELECT table error:${error}`)});
       if(!result1.length)
       {
            console.log(`Not found id: ${MyData.id}`);
       }
       else
       {
            let [result2] = await dbP.query('SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `id2` = ?', [MyData.id2]).catch((error)=>{console.log(`query SELECT table2 error: ${error}`)});
           if(!result2.length)
           {
                /*Тут выполняется мелкий код в виде цикла*/
                await dbP.query('INSERT INTO `table2` (`id2`, `param1`, `param2`, `param3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 0)', [MyData.id2, param1, param2])
               .then(() =>
               {
                    Sio.to(socket.id).emit("MyResultEmmit", MyData);

               }).catch((error) => {console.log(`query INSERT table2 error: ${error}`)});//Часто получаю тут ошибку Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' Хотя запись с этим айди уже существует ощущение такое как буд-то запрос не успел обработаться перед верхним
               }
                else
               {
                    /*Тут снова выполняется мелкий код в виде цикла*/
                    await dbP.query('UPDATE `table2` SET `param1` = ?, `param2` = ? WHERE `id2` = ?', [param1, param2, MyData.id2])
                .then(() =>
               {
                    Sio.to(socket.id).emit("MyResultEmmit", Event);
               }).catch((error)=>{console.log(`query UPDATE table2: ${error}`)});
            }
         }
         unlock();
       });
   });

function Mutex() 
{
    let current = Promise.resolve();

    this.lock = () => 
    {
        let _resolve;
        const p = new Promise(resolve => { _resolve = () => resolve()});
        const rv = current.then(() => _resolve);
        current = p;
        return rv;
    };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

А какой тип у таблиц в базе? Если MyISAM, то ничего удивительного. Для таких таблиц блокировка при транзакции происходит на уровне всей таблицы. Преобразуйте их в InnoDB и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Они и так были InnoDB, проблема была в отсутствии очереди, решил проблему mutex